# Use openssh for ssh connections and for public sftp

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, sftp, guest-account

I have a system to which some users need to connect trough regular SSH. I will name them the “Privileged Users”.
In the same time this system should provide an SFTP server to “Anonymous” user (without any password, or any authentication method).

For the moment, this is my `sshd_config`:

```
########################################################################
# Common conofigurations for both Privileged Users and Anonymous
########################################################################
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
PrintMotd yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
banner /etc/banner
AllowUsers fauve libidiloup anonymous

########################################################################
# Desired connfigurations for Privileged Users (who are not Anonymous)
########################################################################

Match User fauve, libidiloup
    Protocol 2
    IgnoreRhosts yes
    RhostsRSAAuthentication no
    HostbasedAuthentication no
    Port 17129
    PasswordAuthentication no
    PermitEmptyPasswords no
    UsePAM yes
    UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
    ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
    PrintLastLog no
    Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
    KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
    Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
    X11Forwarding yes


########################################################################
# Configuration for Anonymous
########################################################################

Match User anonymous
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PermitEmptyPasswords yes
    ChrootDirectory /mnt/bibliotheque
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    X11Forwarding no
```

I am just worried about the security. Are the configurations of the Anonymous’s block anough?

Especially for the `Protocol`, `RhostsRSAAuthentication`, `HostbasedAuthentication`, `UsePrivilegeSeparation`, `UsePAM` options.

And is this configuration absolutely split the guest Anonymous from Privileged Users capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I made some test and come back with the following feedbacks.

First, this is the final functional `sshd_config` I get:

```
########################################################################
# Common conofigurations for both Privileged Users and Anonymous
########################################################################
Protocol 2
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
PrintMotd yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
banner /etc/banner
AllowUsers fauve anonymous
#AllowGroups sshprivileged

# The following directives could NOT be set on a Match block
UsePAM yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
PrintLastLog no
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256

#########################################################################
## Desired connfigurations for Privileged Users (who are not Anonymous)
#########################################################################

Match User fauve
    IgnoreRhosts yes
    RhostsRSAAuthentication no
    HostbasedAuthentication no
    PasswordAuthentication no
    PermitEmptyPasswords no
    X11Forwarding yes

#########################################################################
## Configuration for Anonymous
#########################################################################

Match User anonymous
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PermitEmptyPasswords yes
    ChrootDirectory /mnt/bibliotheque
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    X11Forwarding no
```

Their is mainly two things witch can not be possible in my first `sshd_config`.

1. The block under the “The following directives could NOT be set on a Match block” comment contain directives witch can not be in a Match block.
2. Their is a conflict between `AllowGroups` and `AllowUsers`. The first directive overwrite the second one.

Comment: The `AllowGroups` and `AllowUsers` parameters have behavior that is not intuitive.  When one of the parameters is present, users matching the parameter's list are allowed **and all other users are denied**.  I haven't tested a config with both parameters present, but I would expect that only users who match **both** lists would be allowed.  Users matching only one or the other list would be denied.

Comment: @SottoVoce yes, the combination between them seams to be not a _xor_ or an _or_ but and _and_.